# Prove this statistic is NOT sufficient

Tags: statistics

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ be a vector of independent identically distributed random variables following $Bin(3,p)$. We consider the estimator $$\hat{p}(X) = X_1/18 + X_2/9 + X_3/6$$ of $p$.

I'd like to prove this statistic is NOT sufficient.

Factorization theorem can't help us here as it only proves a statistic is sufficient when certain conditions are fulfilled. I guess I should try to find an example for which the statement does not hold, straight from the definition of sufficient statistic.

Any help, hints or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statistic is sufficient if $\mathbb{P}(X=x\mid \hat{p}(X)=\hat{p}(x))$ is independent of $p$ for all $x$. So to show that is is not sufficient we must show that for a certain $x$ we have that the above is dependent on $p$. Consider the realization $x=(3,2,3)$. Then, we have that:
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x\mid \hat{p}(X)=\hat{p}(x))=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=x\cap \hat{p}(X)=\hat{p}(x))}{\mathbb{P}(\hat{p}(X)=\hat{p}(x))}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=(3,2,3))}{\mathbb{P}(\hat{p}(X)=8/9)}$$
We have that $\hat{p}(X)=8/9$ if and only if $X=(3,2,3)$ and $X=(1,3,3)$. Therefore, you can write the denominator as:
$$\mathbb{P}(\hat{p}(X)=8/9)=\mathbb{P}(X=(3,2,3))+\mathbb{P}(X=(1,3,3))$$
You can then compute the probabilities using the binomial probability mass function.